# How to create a record type dynamically in Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

How can I create a record type dynamically? Is there any concept of `reflection` or `eval` in ballerina lang?

e.g.

```php
// given this json type that we receive from a client
json j = [{"id": 1}, {"id":2}];

// how can I create a record and subsequently a table ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to create record types dynamically. However, if your requirement is to just create a table from a JSON value, of which you do not know the member structure beforehand, you can use the [`value:fromJsonWithType`](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.value/0.0.0/functions#fromJsonWithType) lang library function to construct the table specifying an appropriate open record (see the [Open Records](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/open-records/) and [Controlling openness](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/controlling-openness/) examples) as the row type.

```
// Same as table<record {| anydata...; |}>
table<record {}> tb = check j.fromJsonWithType();

// If it is known to have an integer `id` field that needs to be used as the key.
// Same as table<record {| readonly int id; anydata...; |}>
table<record {readonly int id;}> key(id) tb2 = check j.fromJsonWithType();
```

Answer (score 2):

A table requires [`readonly` field(s)](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/multiple-key-fields/) as key specifier(s). Therefore, the `record` type (row type) should have at least one readonly required field.

You cannot create a record type dynamically. But you can use [open records](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/open-records/) instead. In your case, if you know that your `json` object has an `id` field which is mandatory and not modified halfway through, you can define an [`open record`](https://ballerina.io/learn/distinctive-language-features/data/#open-records) as below:

```
type Data record {
   readonly int id;
}
```

Then convert your json into an array of `Data` records and add that into the defined table.

```
public function main() returns error? {
    json data = [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}];
    Rec[] records = check data.fromJsonWithType();

    table<Rec> key<int> t = table key(id) [];
    foreach Rec item in records {
        t.add(item);
    }

    io:println(t);
}
```

Optionally, you can modify the `Data` record to include fields which can be optional. Say the received json has a field named `timestamp` which is [optional](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/optional-fields/),

```
type Data record {
   readonly int id;
   string timestamp?;
}
```

Comment: Imesha, your reply is an answer too. I felt the other one was a better one, Thanks for answering though.